# How to find D[F[a(x,y,t),b(x,y,t)],t] in terms of D[F[a(x,y,t),b(x,y,t)],x] and D[F[a(x,y,t),b(x,y,t)],y]?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function $F(a(x,y,t),b(x,y,t))$ whose derivative I would like to be displayed as

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = f(x,y,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + g(x,y,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}
$

right now, I'm only getting

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = f(x,y,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} + g(x,y,t)\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}
$

trying $\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}$ is giving me error that $a(x,y,t)$ is not a valid variable.

P.S.: here I am using $a(x,y)$ as a place holder, the real error message is:

> General::ivar: x Cos[t]+y Sin[t] is not a valid variable.

because in my problem $a(x,y,t) = x\cos t+y \sin t$

Is my approach of  $\frac{\partial F}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial a}$ itself wrong? Any insight appreciated.

EDIT: As suggested, pasting my code from mathematica:

Input:

`D[F[2/√3 (x Sin[((1 - k z) π )/3] + y Sin [(k π z)/3]), 
  2/√3 (-x Sin[(k π z )/3] + y Sin[((1 + k z) π )/3])],
  z]`

Output:

`(1/Sqrt[3]) 2 (-(1/3) k π x Cos[(k π z)/3] + 
    1/3 k π y Cos[1/3 π (1 + k z)]) \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(F\), 
TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[(2 (y Sin[(k π z)/3] + x Sin[1/3 π (1 - k z)]))/Sqrt[3], (2 (-x Sin[(k π z)/3] + y Sin[1/3π (1 + k z)]))/Sqrt[   3]] + (1/Sqrt[3]) 2 (1/3 k π y Cos[(k π z)/3] -  1/3 k π x Cos[1/3 π (1 - k z)])\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(F\),TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[(   2 (y Sin[(k π z)/3] + x Sin[1/3 π (1 - k z)]))/Sqrt[3], (   2 (-x Sin[(k π z)/3] + y Sin[1/3 π (1 + k z)]))/Sqrt[3]]`

Comment: In order to know what is happening you will need to post actual Mathematica code. Also, you say you have a function F of a and b, but then your answer has f and g. Please clarify.

Comment: @bills Updated post to add code. The f and g are place holders, they are not there in my code at all, neither are a and b.